# Why won't sticky navbar scroll over divs with set height and width?

Tags: css, navbar, sticky

Can anyone help?
I've tried to implement a sticky navbar into my website, it worked over one section
however over a section where there are many divs it no longer appears. Any suggestions? Thank you for suggesting the z-index, however, this did not work either. Is there another way I could structure the divs so that I don't have this issue with the navbar disappearing?
I found this resource that could be some help: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="user" href="#about">My Program</a></li>
  <li><a class="user" href="#about">Progressions</a></li>

</ul>




 <div class="float-childL" style="max-width: 50%;">
      <img src="../images/2girls_yoga.jpg" alt="Girls yoga" style="max-width: 100%;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="float-childR" style="max-width: 50%;">
          <h1>TEXT</h1>
          <p>rhrhcjhrctjbrcbhcbhrcbhecbherbhrebhjerbchjebhjrxgvrfewhbfrehfrbhrfbjkwrjkfejnefjnebjcbjcncjbcebjcebjjbbjjbjbwcbhfebhebh</p>
          <br> 
          <br> 
          <br> 
    </div>


    <div class="float-childL" style="max-width: 50%;">
          <h1> TEXT</h1>
      </div>


      <div class="float-childR" style="max-width: 50%;">
        <img src="../images/trio.jpg" alt="male pushup" 
style="max-width: 100%;">
    </div>


    <div class="float-childL" style="max-width: 50%;">
      <img src="../images/male_plank.jpg" alt="plank" 
style="max-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="float-childR" style="max-width: 50%;">
    <h1> TEXT</h1>
</div>
    
    </div>









    ul {
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: -20px;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: rgb(209, 111, 46);
      top: 0;
    }
    
    li {
  float: left;
  
}

     li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

    li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

    .user:hover { 
  background-color: rgb(255, 211, 130);
}

body:after {     
    content: ".";     
    display: block;      
    height: 0;      
    clear: both;      
    visibility: hidden; 
}


    .float-childL {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}  


    .float-childR {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hope you can see HTML and CSS code now?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by adding a `z-index: 2;` to your sticky navbar and then adding `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to your floated div elements.

I'm pretty sure why this is happening is because your floated left and right divs are removed from the normal flow of the page causing them to be positioned over your sticky navbar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried adding this to my code which can be seen above however it didn't work. Have I put it in the right place?

Comment: @Darcy So it's actually because your floated divs are removed from the flow of the page, making the page's height technically the height of your navbar.

You need to clear your floats. Adding this CSS works 
`body:after {
    content: "."; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Comment: Okay thanks very much, I tried adding the new CSS in but I didn't see any changes. Updated the code above.